# How to pass vtkMatrix and std::vector<cv::Point3f> as function parameters?

Tags: c++, class, opencv, vtk

I have a class header file myclass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkMatrix4x4.h>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>

class myclass
{
 public:
     double compute(vtkMatrix4x4 *transMat, std::vector<Point3f>* sourcePoints);
};

  #endif // MYCLASS_H
```

And my myclass.cpp is:

```
#include <myclass.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkMatrix4x4.h>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>

using namespace std;

double myclass::compute(vtkMatrix4x4 *transMat, std::vector<Point3f>* sourcePoints)
{
  double x;
  ......code for computing x......
  ................................
  return x;
}
```

This returns error when I implement:

```
 myclass myFunctions;
 std::vector<cv::Point3f> sourcePoints;
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4> mat =  vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4>::New();
 ...........mat and sourcePoints filled..................
 double c = myFunctions.compute(mat, sourcePoints);
```

Should I declare the vtkMatrix and sourcePoints as private attributes in header file? I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Your class is called `MyClass` but you qualify your function, when you define it, with `myclass`. Case is important.

Comment: That was a typo. Edited it. Still it returns error. I guess the argument-->vector of cv::Point3f should not be pointers.

Comment: My original code contains a lot of other functions which works. Only this portion doesn't work. It would be pointless to copy paste the whole code.

Comment: I don't expect you to cut.n.paste the whole code. Just the parts you think have errors. When you type the code in then its not the same code. New typing = new bugs.

Comment: `double c = myclass.compute(mat, sourcePoints);` Don't you want to create an object of `class myclass` and call your member function from the object you create?

Comment: Cross-checked. There aren't any typos.

Yes, I have an object of [link]class myclass[/link] named [link]myFunctions[/link]

Comment: Just saying its easier for people to help you if you give them the *actual* code that's broken rather than typing in some fresh code that you hope contains the same problem.

Comment: But in the code you give here your object of type `myclass` is called `myclass` which is an error in itself.

Comment: When you declare your `compute()` function in your header file it needs a semicolon at the end.

Comment: @OP: What error do you get?

Comment: Solved it.

The problem was std<vector>(cv::Point3f) sourcePoints was passed as a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

- if you are using smartpointers, you will have to *stick* with them. *never* try to 'pull out the pointer', please, you will wreck its internal refcounts (and defeat its purpose).
- prefer to pass a vector by *reference*, not by *pointer*

---

```
class myclass
{
 public:
     double myclass::compute(vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4> mat, const std::vector<Point3f>& sourcePoints)
};
double myclass::compute(vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4> mat, const std::vector<Point3f>& sourcePoints)
{
  double x;
  ......code for computing x......
  ................................
  return x;
}

 // now you can call it in the desired way:   
 myclass myFunctions;
 std::vector<cv::Point3f> sourcePoints;
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4> mat =  vtkSmartPointer<vtkMatrix4x4>::New();
 double c = myFunctions.compute(mat, sourcePoints);
```

Comment: double myclass::compute(vtkMatrix4x4 *mat, const std::vector<Point3f> sourcePoints)

worked for me.

Comment: yes, that will *compile*. but you already got a dangling pointer, and chances are high, that it will crash at runtime a week later (and you will never know why)

Comment: please read up on smart pointers and their purpose. DO NOT FIGHT them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions. :-)

Comment: I must disagree with the absolute, never try to 'pull out the pointer'.  A reference to a smart pointer is useful when you know that the pointer can't go out of scope during the operation.  Making copies of smart pointers is not a free operation.